# Angular JS orderBy not working using dropdown

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to do `orderBy` using `dropdown` value, but its not working :(

CODE:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.datas = [{
        "id": "1",
            "name": "name area 1"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
            "name": "name area 2"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
            "name": "name area 3"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
            "name": "name area 4"
    }];
    $scope.dropdown = [{
        "title": "Newest first",
            "value": "true"
    }, {
        "title": "Oldest first",
            "value": "reverse"
    }];
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
          <ul ng-repeat="rows in datas | orderBy: 'id':orderByData">
              <li>{{rows.id}} : {{rows.name}}</li>
          </ul>
          <select ng-model="orderByData" ng-options="x.value as x.title for x in dropdown"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[DEOM JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/mebucude/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you use reverse?
Please use false instead reverse and it should work fine.

```
$scope.dropdown = [{
        "title": "Newest first",
            "value": "true"
    }, {
        "title": "Oldest first",
            "value": "false"
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `reverse` parameter here. Instead you can do something like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="rows in datas | orderBy: getSort()">
    <li>{{rows.id}} : {{rows.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Where `getSort` is defined as:

```
$scope.getSort = function() {
    return $scope.orderByData ? 'id' : '-id';
};
```

Basically you want sort part to look like `orderBy: 'id'` or `orderBy: '-id'`.

#### Demo: http://jsbin.com/pepureta/1/edit?html,js,output